# Implement two conditions in the presentation of data

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I created an image gallery. This gallery may or may not have several types `(A, B ...).

To present the types I am missing the following array: `Cats = ["A", "B"]`.

The images only appear when this array is filled, that is, the size is different from `0` or `undefined`.

How can I display images, usually, when the size of the Cat array is `0` or `undefined`?

When the cat array has these conditions, the images appear normally, when the array is different from `undefined` or greater than `0`, it presents the images separated by types as shown in the figure.

Is there a way to implement this without creating two "html"? Can someone help me?

```
<div style="margin-left: 16px; margin-right: 16px;" class="first" *ngIf="Cats != undefined">
    <div *ngFor="let cat of Cats">
        <div *ngIf="counts[cat]">
            <div class="row">
                <span class="nomeCategoria">{{cat}}</span>
            </div>
            <ul class="mdc-image-list my-image-list">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let it of items">
                    <li class="mdc-image-list__item" *ngIf="it.Cat == cat">
                        <div class="mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container">
                            <ng-container *ngIf="it.image == null; else itImage">
                                <img src="./assets/image-not-found.svg" class="mdc-image-list__image imagenotfound">
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-template #itImage>
                                <img [src]="it.image" class="mdc-image-list__image">
                            </ng-template>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ng-container>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When the array is empty you want to display all the 3 images? If yes, just iterate over items in another loop below?

Comment: @NicholasK
Yes, that's right. If you have something in the array it separates the images by type (as is) and that array is empty, it shows the 3 images of the object normally. I didn't understand what you meant :(

Comment: Is [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/delete-if-not-working) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I'll check if `Cats` array is empty and if it's then I'll populate an array with all items Cat. Something like this:

```
export class AppComponent  {

ngOnInit(){
  this.checkCatsArray()
}

Cats=[]

items=[
  {
    ID:1,
    Cat:"A",
   image:"https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/2x3/3.jpg",
},
  {
    ID:2,
    Cat:"B",
   image:"https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/3x2/10.jpg",
},
  {
    ID:3,
    Cat:"M",
   image:"https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/2x3/6.jpg",

},
]

get counts() {
    return this.items.reduce((obj, value) => {
      if (value.Cat in obj) {
        obj[value.Cat]++;
      } else {
        obj[value.Cat] = 1;
      }

      return obj;
    }, {});
  }

checkCatsArray() {
  if (this.Cats.length == 0) {
    for (let cat of this.items) {
      this.Cats.push(cat.Cat)
    }
  }
}
}
```

In this scenario, I didn't touch HTML and I got the desired result - show every Cat if Cats array is empty. Maybe you need to configure `checkCatsArray()` at your own but I believe that this is something that you are looking for.

Hope that will help!

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me, but that is not what I intend. I intend to work with the array and with the object and if the array is not, separate the images by types as it is in the image, if the array is empty, it shows the 3 images that contain the object.

Comment: Np. Maybe I have something in my mind but in this case, we need to change html as well, is this suitable for you?

Comment: What I did in this case was to create two html in which only the condition changed, it works but it gives an idea that it is very slow to load. Is there a way to create this just in an html block?

Comment: I'll look into and try to find something but I don't think that this is a very bad solution also.